# How to use serialPort1 over 2 Forms?

Tags: c#, c++, arduino, serial-port

I am having trouble with using serialPort1 in both of my forms. I have opened the serialPort but it just isn't receiving or sending anything. Am I not able to do it this way or is there a simpler way of doing this. Please let me know.

**Form 1 Code**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Arduino_GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void d1(string indata);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void onButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("A"); // on
        }

        private void offButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("a"); // off 
        }

        private void btnOForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form 2 Code**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace Arduino_GUI
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public delegate void d1(string indata);
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serialPort1.Open();
        }


        private void btnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.WriteLine("2");
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // receiving data
        {
            String indata = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            d1 writeit = new d1(Write2Form);
            Invoke(writeit, indata);
        }

        public void Write2Form(string indata) 
        {
            char firstchar;
            string test;

            firstchar = indata[0];
            switch (firstchar)
            {
                case 'r':
                    test = indata.Substring(1);
                    label1.Text = test;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.Show();
            f1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Arduino Code**

```
String data;
char d1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  
  if(Serial.available()){
    data = Serial.readString();
    d1 = data.charAt(0);  
    switch(d1){    // select action based on first character

      case '2':    // Do when Form2 opens
      Serial.println('r');
      break;
      
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for going through this all and I hope you can help me.

**:)**

Comment: You can create a class and its instances that handle serial ports that are independent of both forms. And if it is not open, open it, and if it is already open, you can continue to use it without closing it.

Comment: Sorry @kuinf, I'm a bit new to c# code so would you mind writing an example for me?

Comment: In addition to that, it is necessary to create a mechanism to arbitrate or exclusively control between the forms as to which form should handle the received data.

Comment: I was planning on having both forms receiving and sending out their own data one they have been opened (only one open at a time). So is what your saying is that I can't do that and will have to make 1 form do the receiving and the other do the sending? @kunif

Comment: Opening/closing a port every time communication is a wasteful operation, and delays and data omissions are likely to occur. For example, why not find and utilize such an existing library? [Top 20 NuGet serialport Packages](https://nugetmusthaves.com/tag/serialport), [MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net), [genielabs/serialport-lib-dotnet](https://github.com/genielabs/serialport-lib-dotnet), [serial port library c# Code Example - Code Grepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/serial+port+library+c%23)